# Sending e-mail from contacts.google.com/preview with a client other than GMail

Tags: thunderbird, google-contacts

I like the new [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/preview/all) but it bugs me that I can't open a new Thunderbird message by clicking contact's e-mail address. When I click an e-mail address in the contact details, GMail new message opens. Here's a [screenshot of what I mean](http://ctrlv.cz/shots/2015/06/15/ccfO.png).

I don't think this can be set up "officially" as I didn't find anything in the Settings. I wonder though, if anyone can find a way to duct tape it. A bookmarklet that alters javascript hooked-up to the html element, or something.

I already sync my Thunderbird with Google Contacts so I could use TB to search for contacts. TB 38 even supports searching multiple address books so it actually wouldn't be that difficult. But I like the web interface to Google Contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with a bookmarklet.

```js
(function(){
  if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
    var done = false;
    js = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    js.type = 'text/javascript';
    js.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js';
    js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
        done = true;
        initMyBookmarklet();
      }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  } else {
    initMyBookmarklet();
  }

  function processClick(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {
      window.location = 'mailto:' + $(this).text();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  };

  function initMyBookmarklet() {
    (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
      $('.wDPsO')
        .off('click')
        .on('click', processClick);

      $(document)
        .off('mousedown', '.jNJq8')
        .on('mousedown', '.jNJq8', processClick);
    })();
  }
})();
void(0);
```

You can get the bookmarklet here: http://pepa.info/google-contacts/